# Push Array Value to Ajax [JQuery / PHP / HTML]

Tags: php, jquery, html

I can't push the value of my array to my php file.

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var item_code = [];

  $('#save').click(function() {
    var item_name = [];
    var item_value = [];
    var item_quantity = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < item_code.length; i++) {
      item_code.push($(this).val());
    }


    $('.item_name').each(function() {
      item_name.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('.item_value').each(function() {
      item_value.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('.item_quantity').each(function() {
      item_quantity.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: "insert2.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        item_name: item_name,
        item_code: item_code,
        item_value: item_value,
        item_quantity: item_quantity,
      },
      success: function(data) {

      }

    });

</script>
```

I have a value storing at "item_code" whenever I search the item code on my search bar. And after that, I want to push the value of item_code[] on the insert2.php.

I'm not getting any error, but the system itself is frozen.

Comment: Why are you looping over `item_code` and pushing onto the same array? That will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish there? If `item_code` already contains the list of items, you don't need another loop.

Comment: For clarification, i want to store in the ID of the item_code in the var item_code = [];

Comment: What do you mean by "the ID of the item_code"?

Comment: `$(this).val()` is the value of the `#save` button.

Comment: Are you sure `item_code` needs to be an array? If all the values are the same, it can just be a single parameter.

Comment: Every item on my dbase have an ID or ID Number. Scenario: I'm search the Item Code of a certain item, and whenever I save an item, instead of the Item Code i want to save, i want the ID or the ID Number is i want to save. And the value of ID Number, is successfully restoring at the item_code[] array..

Comment: It's still not clear, where does the ID come from?

Comment: The ID is the Primary Key of the item...

Comment: That's in the database, where is it in JavaScript or HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the time.. I've already resolved the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that "item_code" variable is also declared globally somewhere else in your code, otherwise there would be no point in iterating through it. Try using a different name instead of "item_code" to send it to "insert2.php".

```
   for (var i = 0; i < item_code.length; i++) {
      item_code.push($(this).val());
   }
```

You can't push data into the same array that you are looping because you will never reach the end of it, unless the memory limit will tell you otherwise. Declare "item_code_second" and push into that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var item_code_second = [];
```

and change your loop:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < item_code.length; i++) {
      item_code_second.push($(this).val());
   }
```

also you are pushing the same value "$(this).val()" as many times as there are values in item_code, which is not making any sense and the exact same value in name, quantity and value. $(this) represents the button that was pushed, don't forget you are in an on click event.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for your time. That's exactly what I do. Hehehehe.

Comment: @Roseheim if the solution solves your problem make sure to mark it as answer and/or upvote